# Page transition in Windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to display a page above page in Windows phone 7

such that the second page is transparent and when it becomes above (pop-up) the first one I want to still be able to see the first page.

Answer (score 0):

You would better use `UserControl` s. Implement each page as a `<UserControl>` and load them accordingly into the `MainPage.xaml`.

I would suggest you to have a look at the [MVVM for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg521153%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)